# ImageMagick video filter for FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick

I'd like to apply some non-trival video operations on a per-frame base.

So far, I've been using shell scripts + ImageMagick + FFmpeg, decomposing the video into individual frames on disk, processing them through ImageMagick and putting it back together, which has an awful OS and disk overhead.

Now it occurred to me there might be an ImageMagick video filter, which accepts just the same parameters as the [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php#options) interface does.

Does something likewise exists?  What can I use instead?

Comment: There's no ImageMagick filter for FFmpeg. What are the non-trivial operations you have to perform?

Comment: All kind of stuff for which I guess there are no filters.   Color space transformation, image compositing, spline drawing, etc., etc.

Comment: Did you check if there are no filter? ffmpeg has a ton of filters. http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/FilteringGuide If all else fails you might have to write your own. Going through ImageMagick will be slow...